# Convert 5D tensor to 4D tensor in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

In PyTorch I have a 5D tensor `X` of dimensions `B x 9 x C x H x W`. I want to convert it into a 4D tensor `Y` with dimensions `B x 9C x H x W` such that concatenation happens channel wise.

To illustrate let,

```
a = X[1,0,:,:,:]
b = X[1,1,:,:,:]
c = X[1,2,:,:,:]
...
i = X[1,8,:,:,:]
```

Then in the tensor `Y`, `a to i` should be channel wise concatenated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(3, 4, 3, 2, 6)
print(x.shape)
y=x.flatten(start_dim=1, end_dim=2)
print(y.shape)
```

---

```
torch.Size([3, 4, 3, 2, 6])
torch.Size([3, 12, 2, 6])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily broadcast to a new shape with [`torch.reshape`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.reshape.html4):

```
b, n, c, h, w = X.shape
X = X.reshape(b, n*c, h, w)
```